# Using glDrawArrays to upload frame buffers?

Tags: opengl

I'm attempting to create a software renderer for my tile based game and got stuck in the most important step : which is copying pixel chunks 
to frame buffer.

First off , here's my class :

```
struct pixel_buffer
{
    int width,height,bytesPerPixel;
    unsigned char* pixels;
    pixel_buffer()
    {
        pixels = NULL;
    }

    pixel_buffer(const char* imageName)
    {
        Image i = LoadImage(imageName);
        width = i.width();
        height = i.height();
        bpp = i.bpp();
        pixels = i.duplicate();
        i.destroy();
    }

    pixel_buffer(int w,int h,int bpp)
    {
        width = w;
        height = h;
        bytesPerPixel = bpp;
        pixels = new unsigned char[w*h*bpp];
    }

    ~pixel_buffer()
    {
        delete pixels;
    }

    void attach(int x,int y,const pixel_buffer& other)
    {
        //How to copy the contents of "other" at x,y offset of pixel buffer ?
    }
};

//This is the screen buffer and the contents get uploaded with glDrawArrays
pixel_buffer screen(640,480,4);

//This is a simple tile
pixel_buffer tile("files\\tiles\\brick.bmp");

//Attach tile to screen at offset 50,10
screen.attach(50,10,tile);
```

And this is the part that confuses me:

```
void attach(int x,int y,const pixel_buffer& other)
{
//How to copy the contents of "other" at x,y offset of pixel buffer ?
}
```

Im not sure how i am supposed to attach("copy") the pixel buffer of the tile to the screen buffer.
I tried this but didn't worked :

```
void attach(int x,int y,const pixel_buffer& other)
{
memcpy(&pixels[x + y * (this->width * this->bpp),other.pixels,other.width * other.height * other.bpp);
}
```

So i would like to ask for some help :-D

Comment: Where exactly do you see OpenGL in that picture? I have no idea, what your actual problem is.

Comment: I call glDrawPixels to draw the Screen buffer.The rendering works , i just can't get the right  offset when i attempt to copy other buffers on top of the screen(frame) buffer....

Comment: OpenGL doesn't work that way. OpenGL operates within the viewport of a frame buffer. glDrawPixels operates relative to the so called *raster position*. But that's obsolete anyway, glDrawPixels always performed poorly, so it got removed and recommended practice is to use textured quads. What puzzles me even more is, that you're writing a software rasterizer, but want to use OpenGL as a backend… Hello, OpenGL itself is a full blown, programmable feature rich rasterizing API on itself, and usually HW accelerated. The key point of a SW rasterizer is, that it operates independently.

Comment: This is a software renderer , i only use opengl because my framework is based on it so i can test it easily...

Comment: I think OpenGL is total overkill then, or simply not the right thing for you. Have a look at SDL, this library has been designed originally for use in situations exactly like yours, it gives you direct access to the framebuffer. http://www.libsdl.org/intro.en/usingvideo.html -- unlike OpenGL which does not give you immediate access to the framebuffer, but requires you to use its drawing primitives. After all OpenGL is as a rasterizer on its own and is not meant to be used as blitting backend.